# List Alternative Names on Info Page

Tags: website-design, layout

I'm designing a website for sharing sheet music. As many songs are often known by different names, I'd like to incorporate those somehow into the informational page for each song. For example, "Piano Sonata No. 11 in A major" might also be searched by "Rondo alla Turca" or "K. 311". I'm not sure how to display those.

Here's the current title panel:

[image: Original]

Here's some ideas I've thought of:

[image]
[image]

What would be the best way to display this data?

Answer (score 1):

**Put it on a separate line.**  This helps the "official" title stand out.

**You might make it (slightly) less prominent.**  I would say that title and composer are the most important, and put it on a third line below that.  It could be a slightly smaller font, too.  I wouldn't bury it too much, though, because a user who searched for the alternative name ought to be able to see this easily--otherwise they might think they ended up on the wrong piece.

Call it "other names" or "also known as".  "Nicknames" isn't quite right.

**Also, [make sure the alternative names come up in the Google Search results snippet](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2672315?hl=en)**.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure about this, but I hope it could be a start

[image]